# In firebase blaze plan's Realtime Databse, for upto how much simultaneous connections, I will not be charged?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know, In firebase blaze plan's Realtime Databse, for upto how much simultaneous connections, I will not be charged? Or the charge does'nt completely depend on simultaneous connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are no charges based on simultaneous connections.  There are just limitations for technical reasons.  Please see the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for a description of the ways that you're billing for Realtime Database usage.

Comment: Thank you for your help.